# Running a var-arg command

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

When I am sending no command line arguments to the program `Yippee's`  `main()` method the output is , `No output` and if I am running the program with command line arguments

`java Yippee 1 2 3 4` the output is `2,3,4`.

My program is as below

```
public class Yippee
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (int x = 1; x < args.length; x++) {
        System.out.println(args[x] + " ");
      }
    }
}
```

The java command lines are:

```
java Yippee
java Yippee 1 2 3 4
```

In my first attempt to run the program I am not passing any command line arguments, but still I am accessing command line arguments `args[x]` so what I am expecting is runtime exception indicating `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` but there is no exception, could you explain me why there is no exception?

Comment: Are you asking why you don't get an exception when you don't pass any arguments to your method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting exception even you are not passing command line arguments, why because JVM will create an empty array with no elements even there are no command line arguments.

In your for loop you have given condition such that the loop will execute only if the `args` array size is greater that 1.

So first time your `args` size is `zero` so for loop won't be executed so `args[x]` won't be executed that's why there is no exception at run time.

consider the below images to get good idea what is happening.

`java Yippee` will results in below diagram

[image]

`java Yippee 1 2 3 4` will results in below diagram
[image]

Comment: Excellent explanation @Mr.Jhash Venku. Thanks a lot I have never seen such an explanation before

Answer (score 4):

When the array is empty, `args.length` is `0`, so your loop will never run in the first place.

Comment: when running a loop at the first time does it check the condition as well..?

Answer (score 3):

Your loop index should start from `0`, not `1`. When you start in `1`, you skip the first argument.

At least your condition - `x < args.length` - is correct. That's why you don't get any exception when you pass no arguments (since the loop is not entered).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with starting a loop index at a non negative value, when the condition is valid (eg: i < args.length). This is because the loop condition is evaluated first.

On the other hand, if we have `int x = -1`, you would have, `x < args.length -> -1 < 0 =>` the instruction `System.out.println(args[x] + " ");` will be called and do `System.out.println(args[-1] + " ");`, which would throw an exception.